# Как добавить свой пин в yandex map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Никак не могу добавить свой пин в карту, дефолтные норм отображаются.

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.76, 37.64],
      zoom: 10
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
      clusterize: true,
      gridSize: 32,
      clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });

  var BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="balloon" id="{{properties.id}}">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="balloon__close"></a>' +
    '<div class="balloon__title">{{properties.title}}</div>' +
    '<ul class="balloon__list">' +
    '<li class="balloon__item">' +
    '<div class="balloon__text">Адрес:' +
    '<span>{{properties.addr}}</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '<li class="balloon__item">' +
    '<div class="balloon__text">Телефон:' +
    '<span>{{properties.phone}}</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '<li class="balloon__item">' +
    '<div class="balloon__text">Режим работы:' +
    '<span>{{properties.time}}</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '<li class="balloon__item link">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="{{properties.web}}" class="balloon__text balloon__text--link">{{properties.web}}</a>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>');

  // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
  // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
  objectManager.objects.options.set({
    iconImageHref: '../img/pin.svg',
    iconImageSize: [95, 37], // размеры картинки
    iconImageOffset: [-11, -30] // смещение картинки
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  $.ajax({
    url: "../json/map.json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
  });

}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Когда вот такое пишу, то все норм:

```
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset','islands#greenClusterIcons');
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить iconLayout: 'default#image'
Код выглядит так:
`objectManager.objects.options.set({
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: '../img/pin.svg',
    iconImageSize: [95, 37], // размеры картинки
    iconImageOffset: [-11, -30] // смещение картинки
  });`